# Spoon Kettle, remove lines from .csv file based on another .csv

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I've two .csv file:

Numbers.csv

|phoneNumber|

Sending.csv

|phoneNumber|Status|

I need to create a Kettle Job to clean the first .csv file removing all numbers that are present in the `Sending.csv` where the `Status`== FAILED.

Do you have some hint how to do that? I'd find convenient using Javascript scripting if it simplyfies the life.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two text file input, read the files, use any lookup step, then use filter row step to add condition.